# Selecting the same option twice react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I would like to use the react-select multi Select component and be able to select the same option multiple times. However, react-select does not allow one to do this.

I managed to get around this in the following way:

const [selectConteudos, setSelectConteudos] = useState([])

```
<Form.Group className="mb-3">
                            <Form.Label>Buscar conteúdo</Form.Label>
                            <Select
                                id="input-group-edit"
                                value={selectConteudos}
                                onChange={(selectedOptions) => {
                                    const uniqueId = Date.now();
                                    const nomeDoConteudo = selectedOptions.label;

                                    if (!selectedOptions.some((option) => option.value === uniqueId)) {
                                        
                                        selectedOptions = [...selectConteudos, { value: uniqueId, label: nomeDoConteudo }];
                                        setSelectConteudos(selectedOptions);
                                    }
                                }}
                                options={conteudos}
                                isMulti={true}
                                hideSelectOptions={true}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
```

But, when I select an item, its name disappears, and in the list below there is an 'invisible' item. I expected to be able to enter "selectedOptions.label" multiple times.[Here is a screenshot of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfN1V.png)